# Batch size is 0 or NaN. Please choose a non-zero fraction

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

While using tensorflow.js we are adding Images to train but we got error while training those image.

```
        const gorra = new Image();
        gorra.src = "https://ml5js.org/docs/assets/img/bird.jpg";
        gorra.width = 224;
        gorra.height = 224;
        console.log("adding images DONE", gorra);

        img2 = new Image();
        img2.src = "{!$Resource.cat}"
        img2.width = 224;
        img2.height = 224;
        console.log(img2);

        console.log("setup classifier");

        console.log("adding example image...");
        const ex = await classifier.addImage(document.getElementById('imgshow'), "Gorra");
        console.log("adding ex image DONE!...", ex);
        const ex1 = await classifier.addImage(img2, "Gorra1");
        console.log("adding ex1 image DONE!...", ex1);

        console.log("Training");
        const trainer = await classifier.train();
        console.log("Training DONE", trainer);
```

Please help me to find where those images added and why it gives that error.

Thak

Comment: can you share the methods train and addImage of classifier ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your second image source is not correct or that image is not loading in memory and you are training on one image and classifier needs at least 2 images for training purpose.
Also see this:
https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-library/issues/212

Comment: Yes, I tried with more than 2 image set. That worked but it again got stuck to train() method of Mobilenet.js. Which says 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is not a function'

Comment: It is difficult to figure out  your problem with this provided code. Can you share code of initializing  classifier variable